# Array.Add vs +=

Tags: arrays, powershell

I've found some interesting behaviour in PowerShell Arrays, namely, if I declare an array as:

```
$array = @()
```

And then try to add items to it using the `$array.Add("item")` method, I receive the following error:

> Exception calling "Add" with "1" argument(s): "Collection was of a fixed size."

However, if I append items using `$array += "item"`, the item is accepted without a problem and the "fixed size" restriction doesn't seem to apply.

Why is this?

Comment: Related: [Why should I avoid using the increase assignment operator (+=) to create a collection](https://stackoverflow.com/q/60708578/1701026)

Answer (score 329, accepted):

When using the `$array.Add()`-method, you're trying to add the element into the existing array. An array is a collection of fixed size, so you will receive an error because it can't be extended.

`$array += $element` creates a **new** array with the same elements as old one + the new item, and this new larger array replaces the old one in the `$array`-variable

> You can use the += operator to add an element to an array. When you
>   use
>       it, Windows PowerShell actually creates a new array with the values of the
>       original array and the added value. For example, to add an element with a 
>       value of 200 to the array in the $a variable, type:
>
> ```
>     $a += 200
> ```

Source: [about_Arrays](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh847882.aspx)

`+=` is an expensive operation, so when you need to add many items you should try to add them in as few operations as possible, ex:

```
$arr = 1..3    #Array
$arr += (4..5) #Combine with another array in a single write-operation

$arr.Count
5
```

If that's not possible, consider using a more efficient collection like `List` or `ArrayList` (see the other answer).

Comment: Thanks :) Thought it may be something like this but thought it would inefficient with large arrays, so the powershell team were doing something different.

Comment: So should be use a c# list instead of a Powershell array when having to do this?

Comment: It depends. If you are going to add and remove a lot of members then yes, try `List` or `ArrayList`. They will be much faster. I personally use `+=` and array 99% of the time because I usually create short throw-away scripts where the extra seconds doesn't matter. For big scripts with lots of add/remove where I want to optimize and save time I use `List` or `ArrayList`.

Comment: As arrays are always of a fixed size, does anyone know why the `Add()` method exists?

Comment: Because it's inherited from `IList`. Try `Get-Member -InputObject @()` will show this `Add   Method   int IList.Add(System.Object value)`

Comment: So they have `.Add()` because they implement IList, but it doesn't work because they are `.IsFixedSize`. So why are they fixed size?? Why does IList have an property to check for a fixed size list thing?

Comment: Note that Arrays implements IList via *explicit interface*. In C#, eg, `var x = new int[0]; x.Add(1);` would be type-invalid and not compiler. PowerShell 'allows' it via dynamic member access, but fails at runtime due to being invalid as .NET array types have a fixed size - ref. https://stackoverflow.com/q/38117870/2864740

Answer (score 171):

If you want a dynamically sized array, then you should make a list. Not only will you get the `.Add()` functionality, but as @frode-f explains, dynamic arrays are more memory efficient and a better practice anyway.

And it's so easy to use.

Instead of your array declaration, try this:

```
$outItems = New-Object System.Collections.Generic.List[System.Object]
```

Adding items is simple.

```
$outItems.Add(1)
$outItems.Add("hi")
```

And if you really want an array when you're done, there's a function for that too.

```
$outItems.ToArray()
```

Comment: I have tried this. I create it using New-Object System.Collections.Generic.List[string] but then if I do .GetType, it tells me it is an array.

Comment: Have you tried using the `Add()` function? I can confirm, if you create a generic `List` object as stated above, you have a mutable list for which you can add and remove items using the `Add()` and `Remove()` methods respectively.

Comment: @Preza8: `(New-Object System.Collections.Generic.List[string]).GetType().Name` yields `List\`1` for me, as expected; perhaps you applied `+=` to the variable containing the list (rather than calling the `.Add()` method), in which case the variable value would indeed be converted to an array (`System.Object[]`).

Comment: **Shortcut: `$a = new-object collections.generic.list[object]`**

Comment: is this the same as: `$arr = New-Object System.Collections.ArrayList`?

Answer (score 19):

The most common idiom for creating an array without using the inefficient `+=` is something like this, from the output of a loop:

```
$array = foreach($i in 1..10) { 
  $i
}
$array
```

Adding to a preexisting array:

```
[collections.arraylist]$array = 1..10
$array.add(11) > $null
```

Comment: I really like this approach. It's much more succinct without loss of intent/clarity

Comment: @js2010 Don't quite understand this. How would you APPEND a new value to an existing array using this approach?

Comment: @Jay I think that comes up less often, but an arraylist would be more efficient than copying the whole array over again with +=.