# PowerShell Remove item [0] from an array

Tags: arrays, powershell, arraylist

I'm struggling a bit to remove the first line (item ID) of an array.

```
$test.GetType()

IsPublic IsSerial Name                                     BaseType                                                                                                      
-------- -------- ----                                     --------                                                                                                      
True     True     Object[]                                 System.Array
```

To list all the options I tried `,$test | gm` and it clearly states:

```
Remove         Method                void IList.Remove(System.Object value)                                                                                              
RemoveAt       Method                void IList.RemoveAt(int index)
```

So when I try `$test.RemoveAt(0)` I get the error:

```
Exception calling "RemoveAt" with "1" argument(s): "Collection was of a fixed size."At line:1 char:1
+ $test.RemoveAt(1)
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (:) [], MethodInvocationException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : NotSupportedException
```

So I finally found [here](http://www.jonathanmedd.net/2014/01/adding-and-removing-items-from-a-powershell-array.html) that my array needs to be of the type `System.Object` to be able to use `$test.RemoveAt(0)`. Is it best practice to declare all the arrays in the beginning of the script as a list? Or is it better to convert the arrays with `$collection = ({$test}.Invoke())` to a list later on when this functionality is needed?

What are the pro's and cons of both types? Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 60, accepted):

An alternative option is to use Powershell's ability to [assign multiple variables](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_assignment_operators?view=powershell-7.1#assigning-multiple-variables) (see [this other answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37733801)).

```
$arr = 1..5
$first, $rest= $arr

$rest
2
3
4
5
```

It's been a feature of Powershell for over a decade. I found this functionality from [an MSDN blog post](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/powershell/2007/02/05/powershell-tip-how-to-shift-arrays/):

Comment: This is the best solution by far! I'll be using this one from now on, thanks.

Comment: This method is unreliable if you want `$rest` to have a consistent data type. If the `$arr` has only 2 elements, `$rest` will be a scalar, otherwise array or even null

Comment: Unless `$rest` is already an array type, in which case it will remain an array type.
So `$first,$arr = $arr` should work just fine.
You can also force the issue with: `$first,[object[]]$rest = $arr`

Comment: Or to simulate "shift left": 
`$null, $arr= $arr`

Comment: This does not work if $arr has 0 or 1 element. `$arr=@(1); $first, $arr = $arr; $arr.gettype()` results $arr being null instead @(). It may not work if $arr has two elements, it results $arr being a scalar as comment #2 said.

Comment: This doesn't work. Do it to an array with 2 elements. You will no longer have an array. That is a serious failure.

Comment: @spongyryno See the comment from Willem M. above yours.  It addresses your observation.

Comment: In PowerShell 7, Willem M's comment is half-right: array-typing `$rest` works if the original array is of size 2 or greater, but if it is of size 1, the resulting variable will always be null, even when explicitly typing all variables in the expression.

Answer (score 34):

Arrays are fixed-size, like the error says. `RemoveAt()` is an inherited method that doesn't apply to normal arrays. To remove the first entry in the array, you could overwrite the array by a copy that includes every item except the first, like this:

```
$arr = 1..5

$arr
1
2
3
4
5

$arr = $arr[1..($arr.Length-1)]

$arr
2
3
4
5
```

If you need to remove values at different indexes then you should consider using a `List`. It supports `Add()`, `Remove()` and `RemoveAt()`:

```
#If you only have a specific type of objects, like int, string etc. then you should edit `[System.Object] to [System.String], [int] etc.
$list = [System.Collections.Generic.List[System.Object]](1..5)

$list
1
2
3
4
5

$list.RemoveAt(0)

$list
2
3
4
5
```

See my earlier [SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14620290/powershell-array-add-vs/14620446#14620446) and [about_Arrays](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh847882.aspx) for more details about how arrays work.

Comment: `$arr[1..($arr.Length-1)]` does not work for arrays of length 1 (one would expect it to return empty array, but it does not). Use this if that may be a problem: `$upperBound = (1, ($args.length-1) | measure-object -max).maximum; $userProvidedArgs = $args[1..$upperBound]`

Comment: Good point. I would've tried `$arr[1..([math]::max(1,($arr.length-1)))]`

Comment: I suggest using `$arr[1..$arr.length]`, this is not only shorter but also works better in case `$arr` has only a single element. Then your method will not strip the element, this one does.

Comment: this is a very interesting solution converting to list (easy)... 
I guess this would be a great solution co-working with a casting 
(when we know the definitive object we want) for further work with .net library code...

Answer (score 25):

You can use [`Select-Object -Skip <count>`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/select-object?view=powershell-6) to omit the first *count* item(s):

```bsh
PS C:\> 1..3 | Select-Object -Skip 1
2
3
PS C:\>

PS C:\> 1 | Select-Object -Skip 1
PS C:\>
```

Comment: Thank you, this is exactly what I was looking for. Using -Skip seems easier to read than messing with lengths and indices.

Comment: I really liked the suggestion because of the code clarity, but this approach drove me into some troubles: when the array has two objects, the result is not an array with one object, but the the last object remaining; when the array has only one object, the result is `$null`.

Comment: Hi @ZéCláudio Powershell's default behaviour is to flatten single-item sequences to scalars and empty sequences to `$null`.  To force an array in all cases, wrap the sequence in the [@(...) array subexpression operator](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_operators?view=powershell-6#array-subexpression-operator--).

Answer (score 19):

This will allow you to remove every occurrence of an arbitrary element from an array without resorting to a more sophisticated .NET object.

```
$x=<array element to remove>
$test = $test | Where-Object { $_ -ne $x }
```

Alternatively,

```
$x=<array index to remove>
$test = $test | Where-Object { $_ -ne $test[$x] }
```

This will do the same, but will only remove one of the elements.  If there are duplicates, they will remain.  This can also be done via the index style as above.

```
$x=<array element to remove>
$skip=$true
$test = $test | ForEach-Object { if (($_ -eq $x) -and $skip) { $skip=$false } else { $_ } }
```

Also based on one of the comments, if you're not confident that `$test` is an array, it might be prudent to put `$test=@($test)` first.

Comment: Upvoted, this did the trick for me. And it's nice and concise.

Comment: This can behave incorrectly if the array contains duplicate values.

Comment: Pay attention: when only 1 element is left, the type is String instead of Object[]! The code can be fixed by adding this to the end of the example: `if ($test -is [string]) {  # it's a string when it has only 1 item
 $test= ,$tes  t# make it an array again (with only 1 item)
}
`

Comment: Bravo! Easy and effective!

Answer (score 5):

Just to update - there's an issue with [@Frode F. answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24754822/powershell-remove-item-0-from-an-array/24755250#24755250)

> If the number of elements in array is more than 1

```
$arr = $arr[1..($arr.Length-1)]
```

> If the number of elements is 1, then this doesn't remove the element

```
if($arr.Length -le 1) {
    $arr = @()
}
else {
    $arr = $arr[1..($arr.length - 1)]
}
```

Answer (score 3):

I think it's going to depend on the circumstances.  If you only need to remove that first element once, then you can use array slicing:

```
$arr = $arr[1..($arr.length-1)]
```

If you're going to do it repeatedly, then you should start with an arraylist or generic collection.  If it's a large array, you might want to just put the expression that's creating it into a scriptblock and do an .invoke() on that rather than letting the pipeline create an array and then convert that to a collection.

Answer (score 2):

removeat() works with arraylists (like $error):

```
[collections.arraylist]$a = get-process
$a.removeat(0)
```

Answer (score 0):

Excuse the late answer, but I was struggling with this also. For my intents and purposes (writing to a text file), I realized that since the array was a fixed size -- instead of removing it I could just set the value to string.empty.

```
$results = SQLQuery -connectionString $connectionString  -query $query;
$results[0] = '';
foreach ($r in $results) {
    Add-Content $skus $r[0]; 
}
```

For me this got rid of the header that I didn't want in my flat file.  Hope this helps someone else out there.

Comment: This does not remove anything from the array, which is the purpose of the question.

Answer (score 0):

If we have the case when big array(or ArrayList) must be performed by some parts - I used some lifehack:

```
#$bigArray with thousands of items
while($bigArray.Count -gt 0)
{
    if($bigArray.Count -gt 100)
    {
    $k = 100
    }else {$k = $bigArray.Count}
    $part = $bigArray | select -First $k
#now we can make some operations with this $part
#in the end of loop we should exclude this part from big array
    if($bigArray.Count -gt 100)
    {
        $bigArray = $bigArray | select -Last ($bigArray.Count - $k)
    }else {$bigArray = @()}#in this step we have been handle last part of array and we should null him for stop loop
}
```

And now we can handle big array by some parts(by 100 items)

Answer (score 0):

Combination of other answers with my minor changes (using it as a global function from my $profile):

```
function global:sudo {
    $runArgs = $args

    if($runArgs.Length -le 1) {
        $runArgs = ""
    }
    else {
        $runArgs = $runArgs[1..($runArgs.length - 1)]
        $runArgs = $runArgs -join " "
    }
    
    Start-Process $args[0] -ArgumentList $runArgs -Verb runas    
}
```

So, both `sudo notepad` and `sudo notepad c:\windows\abc.txt` would work, and arguments should be passed gracefully (did not really check thoroughly though)

Answer (score 0):

If you want to delete a row by a known index x (base 0), one could also just copy the lower and the upper part of the array.

**Delete row x from arry**

```
$LastElement = $arry.GetUpperBound(0)

if ($LastElement -ge 0) {

    if ($x -eq 0) {
        $lowerRange = @()
    } else {
        $lowerRange = @($arry[0..($x-1)])
    }

    if ($x -eq $LastElement) {
        $upperRange = @()
    } else {
        $upperRange = @($arry[($x+1)..$LastElement])
    }

    $arry = @($lowerRange; $upperRange)
}
```

Answer (score 0):

There is a more simple and elegant method to do this. This answer also works with arrays that have a single element (unlike some of the other answers previously given). It also works at any desired index.

```
$arr = @(1,2,3)
$arr -ne $arr[0] #remove first element: @(2,3)
$arr -ne $arr[1] #remove second element: @(1,3)
$arr -ne $arr[-1] #remove last element: @(1,2)
```

Comment: Thank you for the addition but be careful with this as it will remove more than just the first element.  This code `$arr = @(1,2,3,1); $arr = $arr -ne $arr[0]; Write-Host $arr` returns `@(2,3)` and not `@(2,3,1)` as expected.

Comment: ah, true. sorry I didn't check my answer with duplicate values.