# Powershell Arraylist RemoveAt not workig

Tags: powershell

I was using powershell Arraylist to hold the list generated by splitting a string. When i try to remove the first item in the list using the below code the enitre list is going null.

```
[System.Collections.ArrayList]$teststringlist=New-Object System.Collections.ArrayList
$teststring ="Test1,Test2,Test3"
$teststringlist = $teststring.Split(",")
$teststringlist=$teststringlist.RemoveAt(0)
```

How i can remove the first item at Index 0 of the Arraylist in powershell

Comment: Please tag your questions only with the language used, not with multiple

Comment: Please try this [see this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53372181/1849480)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`RemoveAt` doesn’t return a value (see https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.arraylist.removeat?view=netcore-3.1) so instead of

```
$teststringlist=$teststringlist.RemoveAt(0)
```

just do this:

```
$teststringlist.RemoveAt(0)
```

Comment: Actually, this is a better answer.

Answer (score 1):

You can do this using the `Select-Object` cmdlet and the `-Skip` parameter:

```
$teststringlist = $teststringlist | Select-Object -Skip 1
```

Alternative you can do it like this:

```
$teststringlist[1 .. ($a.teststringlist)]
```

Comment: Select-Object -Skip 1 always skips the first one?.Do you have any idea why RemoveAt is not working.I was using Arralist because ArrayList isn’t fixed, you can remove elements from them using the Remove() method

Comment: it also works but the it doesn't return anything so when you reassign it with the return method, it is empty. And yes, -skip 1 always skips the first one