# Why System.Array class implements IList but does not provide Add()

Tags: c#, list, system.array

This code:

```
int[] myArr = { 1, 2 };
myArr.Add(3);
```

throws the following error on Build:

> error CS1061: 'System.Array' does not contain a definition for 'Add' and no extension method 'Add' accepting a first argument of type 'System.Array' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

`IList` interface has the `Add()` method, but why the Array does not implement it?

**UPDATE**: I see from the answers that it DOES implement it explicitly, OK, I get it, thank you, I should better stick to the question:

Why `Array` does not actually *provide* `Add()`, OR, better, why did it have to implement `IList` in the first place? Instead of implementing `IList`, it could be another interface (e.g. `IArray`) which could have ONLY the useful for Array members of `IList` -e.g. `IsFixedSize`, `IsReadOnly`, `IndexOf()`... just a thought.

Comment: If you cast it to an `IList`, you'll be able to call `Add` (classes can implement some interfaces [*explicitly*](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/ms173157.aspx) which means that you only get access to (all of) the interfaces methods when treating it as that interface). You'll be disappointed though. Arrays have a fixed size.

Comment: Then why does not the language simply remove the :IList from Array class signature?

Comment: It doesn't. Array implements `IList` - but if you want to use it *as* an `IList`, you have to cast it to a variable of that type.

Comment: @Damien_The_Unbeliever, sorry I corrected the question, I meant why it does not remove it!

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Why array implements IList?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5968708/why-array-implements-ilist)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Yes, it seems that it should have been a better design if `System.Array` had implemented `IReadOnlyList` or alike interface. However, `IReadOnlyList<T>` appeared in **.Net 4.5** while `System.Array` stays from the initial **.Net 1.0**. Microsoft, IMHO, did their best and *hid* `Add` via  *explicit interface implementation*

http://referencesource.microsoft.com/#mscorlib/system/array.cs,156e066ecc4ccedf

```
  ...
int IList.Add(Object value)
{
    throw new NotSupportedException(Environment.GetResourceString("NotSupported_FixedSizeCollection"));
} 
  ...
```

So you can't do

```
int[] myArr = { 1, 2 };

myArr.Add(3);
```

but you can insist on using `Add` (and get `NotSupportedException` thrown) via

```
((IList) myArr).Add(3);
```

Or even

```
if (!myArr.IsFixedSize) {
  // we have very strange array, let's try adding a value to it
  ((IList) myArr).Add(3);
}
```

Answer (score 12):

**Why Array does not actually provide Add()?**

Array has fixed size, so you cannot add new element(s).

> The number of dimensions and the length of each dimension are
>   established when the array instance is created. These values can't be
>   changed during the lifetime of the instance.
>   https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/9b9dty7d.aspx

**Why did it have to implement IList in the first place?**

> Definition of IList:  Represents a non-generic collection of objects
>   that can be individually accessed by index.
>
> https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.collections.ilist.aspx

Array is accessed by index and IList accommodate this index, which is why Array implements IList.

For reference: [Why array implements IList?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5968708/why-array-implements-ilist)

Comment: Then why does it implement IList (which has Add)?

Comment: @cnom you could see here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5968708/why-array-implements-ilist

Answer (score 3):

It does provide Add, but by throwing a `NotSupportedException` (see [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.array%28v=vs.110%29.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396)), because the size of an array is fixed.

The reason why you get a compilation error, instead, is because the interface is implemented explicitly, so if you want to call the method you need to cast to `IList`. See this C# guide about [explicit interface implementation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173157.aspx).

Answer (score 3):

Though a class implementing an interface must implement all members of the interface, it can implement them explicitly:

```
public class MyList<T> : IList<T>
{
    // ... shortened for simplicity
    void ICollection<T>.Add(T item) {  } // explicit implementation
}
```

If you implement the method this way, it won't be visible on instances of `MyList<T>`:

```
MyList<int> list = new MyList<int>();
list.Add(5); // would NOT compile
((IList<int>)list).Add(5); // can be compiled
```

So if you have an `int[]` you *could* do that:

```
int[] array = new int[0];
((IList<int>)array).Add(5);
```

It will compile, but at runtime a `NotSupportedException` will be thrown because **arrays have fixed size** and you cannot *add* a new element to an array as it's size is determined on initialization (`new int[0]`).

Comment: `Add()` is not part of `ICollection`

Comment: @haim770 yes it is: [reference source](http://referencesource.microsoft.com/#mscorlib/system/collections/generic/icollection.cs,a9319db8c62ae453,references)

Comment: You're right. I referred to the non-generic version, which is implemented (explicitly) by `Array` in question

Answer (score 2):

> System.Array class implements IList but does not provide Add()

Of course it does via explicit implementation (there is no way to implement interface and not implement some members).

> Why the array implements `IList`?

Well, mainly to indicate that it supports indexer.

But in fact array implements one of the valid `IList` usages. The `IList` interface has a property called [`IsFixedSize`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.collections.ilist.isfixedsize(v=vs.110).aspx), which according to the documentation

> Gets a value indicating whether the IList has a fixed size.

and then

> A collection with a fixed size does not allow the addition or removal of elements after the collection is created, but it allows the modification of existing elements.

So array implementation returns `IsFixedSize = true` and throws `NotSupportedException` inside `Add`, `Insert`, `Remove` and `RemoveAt` methods.

Comment: Thank you! This is closer to the answer that I need.. I have not accepted an answer yet, because I would like a reason why IList was put there in the first place! There could be another interface (e.g. IArray) which could have ONLY the useful for Array members of IList -e.g. IsFixedSize, IsReadOnly, IndexOf()-

Comment: You are right. AFAIC BCL designers considered such alternatives and decided to take this path. Same for generic `IList<T>` which also has such drawbacks. Starting from .NET 4.5, the `IReadOnlyList<T>` is closest to what array is (but it lacks indexer setter).

Answer (score 1):

According to msdn:

> IList.Add(Object)
>
> Calling this method always throws a NotSupportedExceptionexception.

[Array Class](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.array(v=vs.110).aspx) - see explicit interface implementation section

`Array` has this method. To call this method you should explicitly cast to `IList`. This method can't be called, because array has fixed size and this size can't be dynamically changed.

Answer (score 1):

`IList` is implemented in three different categories:

- Readonly
- Variable size
- Fixed size

Obviously the `Array` type is a fixed size implementation of `IList`.
The reason why you cannot access the `Add()` method from an `Array` is because the method is implemented explicitly:

```
public class A : IList {
    public void IList.Add(object o){
         ...
    }
}
```

This means you need to cast your array to an `IList` before you're able to use the `Add` method (even though it will throw an non-supported exception).

You might say this is a bad design, and many people would agree with you on that.

Read more on explicitly defined interfaces: 
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa288461(v=vs.71).aspx