# How to update ListCollectionView?

Tags: c#, wpf

The context is that I want to expose to a `ListView` in the View a `ListCollectionView` from the ViewModel; that ViewModel updates slowly an `ObservableCollection` (it takes few seconds to fill the collection).

Hence, I want to update a `ListCollectionView` after an `ObservableCollection` was updated this way:

```
MyObservableCollection.CollectionChanged += CollectionChanged;

private void CollectionChanged(object sender, NotifyCollectionChangedEventArgs e)
{
    MyListCollectionView.AddNewItem(e.NewItems);
    MyListCollectionView.CommitNew();
}
```

I tried to update a `ListCollectionView`, but it fails even with a `List<>`. How can I do this ?

```
[TestClass]
public class ListViewTests
{
    private ListCollectionView _sut;

    [TestInitialize]
    public void Setup()
    {
        var toadd = new List<int> {};
        _sut = new ListCollectionView(toadd);
    }

    [TestMethod]
    public void AddItem()
    {
        var toadd = new List<int> { 1,2,3 };
        _sut.AddNewItem(toadd);
        _sut.CommitNew();
    }
}
```

> System.InvalidOperationException: 'AddNewItem' is not allowed for this view.

For more details, how I update the `ObservableCollection`:

```
Parallel.ForEach(ShTiffFiles, file =>
{
    var sht = new ShutterTiff(file, _aesService); // slow (small Model)
    var shtv = new ShutterTiffVignette(sht, _fastCache); // slow (small ViewModel)
    lock (_o) // make it thread safe
    {
        Application.Current.Dispatcher.Invoke(() =>
        {
            ShutterTiffObservableCollection.Add(shtv);
        });
    }
});
```

in the ViewModel:

```
private object _o = new object();
```

Comment: addition to mm8 answer: `var toadd = new List<int> { 1,2,3 };
        _sut.AddNewItem(toadd);` will not work if you change `int[]`  to `List<int>`

Comment: after update: and why ... why you whana use `ListCollectionView` ? instead `ObservableCollection` directly? ... and why if you really need to use LCV you are not using  `MyListCollectionView = new ListCollectionView(MyObservableCollection)` ? then you dont need setup CollectionChanged  event handler

Comment: You can obviously only add `int` values to a `List<int>`. Not another `List<int>`. `toadd` should be an `int` in `AddItem()`.

Comment: You would hardly ever create a ListCollectionView explicitly. Instead, use a CollectionViewSource: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/desktop/wpf/data/how-to-get-the-default-view-of-a-data-collection?view=netframeworkdesktop-4.8

Comment: @Selvin That's the correct point. I don't need to worry about `ListCollectionView`, I only need to add to the `ObservableCollection`. Then what is the `AddNewItem` for ?

Comment: @Soleil-MathieuPrévot mm8 beat me and add this info to his answer,  too, right before I post the comment

Comment: Your original question included a unit test against a `ListCollectionView` so whether you "need" or not depends entirely on the context. But in general, no, you could just add items to the source collection directly.

Comment: @mm8 Are you implying that there are several ways to update ListCollectionView ?

Comment: @Soleil-MathieuPrévot: No. I am saying that I don't see why you need one in the first place as you can modify the source collection directly.

Comment: @mm8 This should be stated in your answer, so I can accept it, it's the core point. Then what is the AddNewItem for ?

Comment: I added a link to the docs where you can read about how collection views work.

Comment: @mm8 I missed that remark indeed. Still, in that case, what is AddNewItem(Object) for ?

Comment: For adding a new item to the view. It doesn't mean that you should use it :)

Comment: @Soleil-MathieuPrévot: Please ask a new question if you have another issue. Don't change the original question.

Comment: @mm8 I did not change the question, I added context details

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change the type of `toadd` in the `Setup()` method to a `List<T>` or any other collection that implements `IList` and actually provides an implementation for the `Add` method:

[Why System.Array class implements IList but does not provide Add()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38117870/why-system-array-class-implements-ilist-but-does-not-provide-add/38117930)

You cannot 'Add' something to an array.

It's also unclear what your test is supposed to do? Verify the functionality of the built-in `ListCollectionView` type? You should focus on testing your code instead of testing framework types.

> *In the end, I want to update a ListCollectionView after an ObservableCollection was updated

Then wrap the `ObservableCollection`:

```
_sut = new ListCollectionView(observableCollection);
```

Or simply modify the `ObservableCollection` directly. You don't seem to need to use a `ListCollectionView` here. A collection view is something that the frameworks creates for you when you bind to a source collection. Please refer to the [docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.data.collectionview?view=netcore-3.1) for more information.

Comment: I really liked your answer. Learned a lot from it
Also maybe she just wanna do some playtesting for something new "things" in the framework and don't do some actual tests

Comment: @styx: Maybe. That's why I wrote "unclear".

Comment: @Soleil-MathieuPrévot: The `ListCollectionView` wraps an array in the `Setup()` method. I edited my answer to clarify this since you also have a `toadd` in the test method.