# JSON Array in PowerShell

Tags: arrays, json, powershell, hashtable

Am trying to generate the below JSON string in PowerShell:

```
[
    {
        "FirstName": "Test",
        "LastName": "Account2"
    }
]
```

The code I have at the moment in PowerShell is:

```
$Body = @{
    @{
        FirstName='Test'
        LastName='Account2'
     }
}
```

The error I get with this is: Missing '=' operator after key in hash literal.

Answer (score 27, accepted):

The outer `[]` is a list in JSON and you're trying to use `@{}`, which is a hashtable in PowerShell. Use `@()` which is an array (list) in PowerShell:

```
$Body = @(
    @{
        FirstName='Test'
        LastName='Account2'
    }
)
ConvertTo-Json -InputObject $Body
```

(and I use -InputObject instead of piping, because PowerShell is obsessed with flattering lists, and drops the list otherwise).

Comment: Thanks! That works a treat. I have also updated the script to use the InputObject as you mentioned. Thanks again!

Comment: This helped me with a similar issue as well, thanks!

Comment: Good point about the -InputObject Vs Piping. Solved my issue.

Answer (score 1):

I had some problems adding new items to the Powershell list. I tried to add an item using the .add() function. This returned the error `"Collection was of a fixed size."`

Adding items to the list is just simple by using the += symbol.

```
$Body += @{FirstName='Test2'; LastName='Account3'}
```

That simple.

Comment: Careful, += is supposed to be pretty expensive because it creates a new array with the new element appended to the end. Then replaces the old array with the new one. See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14620290/array-add-vs