# How to insure json stays array

Tags: arrays, powershell

I want to remove an array element from json array (PSObject) if value matches as follows:

```
$code = 12345
$myObject = @{ ArrayPair= @(@{ code = 12345; perm = "RW" }, @{ code = 23456; perm = "RW" })}

if ($true) { # $revoke
      $myObject.ArrayPair = $myObject.ArrayPair | Where-Object -FilterScript {$_.code -ne $code}
}
```

At the start ArrayPair has 2 array elements, after executing the filter, ArrayPair is no longer an array but rather an object with two elements.   How can I keep it as an array so I can continue to add new pairs to the array?

json Values before and After removal:
Before value:

```
 {"ArrayPair":  [{"perm":  "RW","code":  12345},{"perm":  "RW","code":  23456}]}
```

After Value removal

```
{"ArrayPair":  { "perm":  "RW", "code":  23456 }}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can force the object to stay an array like this:

```
$code = 12345
$myObject = @{ ArrayPair= @(@{ code = 12345; perm = "RW" }, @{ code = 23456; perm = "RW" })}
[array]$myObject.ArrayPair = $myObject.ArrayPair | Where-Object -FilterScript {$_.code -ne $code}

$myObject.ArrayPair.GetType()
#Returns
#IsPublic IsSerial Name                                     BaseType
#-------- -------- ----                                     --------
#True     True     Object[]                                 System.Array
```

To add additional entries to your array you have to try it like this:

```
$myObject.ArrayPair += @{code = 2134; perm= "RR"}
```

This way you can add entries to the array and the result looks like this:

```
PS C:\> $myObject.ArrayPair

Name                           Value
----                           -----
code                           23456
perm                           RW
code                           2134
perm                           RR
```

Please be aware that `+=` doens't really add objects to the array, but instead recreates the array with new values.
If you try to add the objects via `$myObject.ArrayPair.Add(@{code = 2134; perm= "RR"})` you get an error.

Please take a look at this answer for further explanations:
[PowerShell Array.Add vs +=](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14620290/powershell-array-add-vs)

Answer (score 0):

I while deleting elements if there was just one left, I found that I had to double force the object to make sure that it remained an array type:

```
[array]$temp = $result.data.app.roles.admin | Where-Object -FilterScript {$_.club -ne $ClubNo}
$result.data.app.roles.admin = [array]($temp)
```