# Power Shell Simple Script

Tags: powershell-3.0

I am new to Stack Over flow and did not know how to start.
I have around 1500 PC's in my organization
What I want is to write a simple script in PowerShell that will get a list of computers from a text file as input, get the info of my function and save the info to a CSV file as output.

What I am trying to do finding RAM Module capacities
For example if you type

```
WMIC /NODE:MachineName Memorychip get capacity
```

It will give you each module capacity size of remote PC; for example I have a system which has 4 RAM modules installed each of 8 GB so output will be as

> ```
> Capacity
> 8589934592
> 8589934592
> 8589934592
> 8589934592
> ```

it means 4 slots and each is of 8 GB

What I want is to use this simple command to write a script either in command line or in PowerShell (PowerShell is preferred).

To be more specific, here is what I am trying right now

```
$Result = @()
$servers = Get-Content "L:\Data.txt"
Foreach ($s in $servers) {
    $Disk = (WMIC /NODE:$s MemoryChip Get Capacity) 
    $Object = New-Object -TypeName PSCustomObject -Property $Disk
    }
    $Result += $Object
}
$Result | Export-CSV "L:\RAMReport.csv" -NoTypeInformation -Encoding UTF8
```

I hope my question will be to the point

Thank you so much for the help

Comment: What's wrong on `Get-WmiObject -Class Win32_PhysicalMemory -ComputerName $s -Property Capacity` instead of `WMIC.exe`? Or (starting in PowerShell 3.0,) this cmdlet has been superseded by [`Get-CimInstance`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-gb/powershell/module/cimcmdlets/get-ciminstance?view=powershell-5.1)?

Comment: Thank you for the comments, But the thing is it gives total capacity what i need is individual capacity of each RAM Slot
I have System Center as well but it also gives total capacity which in my case not required

Comment: If there is a better way to get the desired results then it would be great

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe the following (partially commented) script could lead to desired solution:

```
$servers = Get-Content "L:\Data.txt"
$Result = Foreach ($s in $servers) {
    $Disk = (WMIC /NODE:"""$s""" MemoryChip Get Capacity) |
        #                ↑↑  ↑↑ remove if $s is already a quoted string
        Where-Object {$_ -ne ''}
    $Prop = @{
        'server' = $s
        "$($Disk[0].Trim())MB" = ($Disk | 
            Select-Object -Skip 1 |
                ForEach-Object { [UInt64]$_ / 1Mb }) -join ' '
    }
    New-Object -TypeName PSCustomObject -Property $Prop
}
$Result # | Export-Csv "L:\RAMReport.csv" -NoTypeInformation -Encoding UTF8
#       ↑ uncomment to export data to a CSV file
```

Explanation:

- `$Result += $Object` is [very expensive array operation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14620290/array-add-vs),
- `wmic /node:"srv-12" MemoryChip Get /Value` requires double-quoted server name if contains some characters (e.g. *Hyphen-Minus*).

**Output** (without exporting data to a CSV file) could look as follows:

```
server   CapacityMB
------   ----------
server1  8192 8192
server_2 8192 8192 8192 8192
server-3 8192
```

Comment: Thank you so much Josefz for pointing me to the right direction. 
Yesterday night i applied this script from my AD and scans all the vlans, got the required results in the morning.

Comment: By the way, yesterday night i asked from Microsoft as well regarding System Center, and found out that i can see physical memory slot wise with capacity from Physical Memory Sub tree under Machine name  Thanks again